# how to use useState in an html tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to link my state to an HTML tag. I managed to do this using class, but now using hooks I am not getting it. an error is appearing.

> React Hook "useState" is called in function "navbar" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function react-hooks/rules-of-hooks.

Code:

```
  export default function navbar() {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen)
    }

    return (
      <nav>
        <div className="logoBtn">

          <div className="logo">
            <a href="#"><h1>Logo</h1></a>
          </div>

          <div className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
            <div className="bar"></div>
            <div className="bar"></div>
            <div className="bar"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <ul className={isOpen ? 'showNav' : und}>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where do you call `handleClick`? I have one GitHub repository which shows how to toggle a class based on click event in function, class and styled components, feel free to take a look - [norbitrial/react-toogle-class-on-click](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-toogle-class-on-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an uppercase first letter for a component name.

That's the reason for the error you currently have.

```
export default function Navbar() {
```